# Problems with loading extensions in otg

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I am testing the otg format and the performance speed is great.

However, I am facing some problems with my extensions. Is there any difference of how the .otg and .svf works with respect to dbIds, nodes or usage of the derivate [api](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of svf2 works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any difference with how you load an extension or design/write it in general but with every new translation the dbids are not guaranteed to be consistent (with both old SVF or SVF 2.0 or any formal official name we'd decide to give it once it's released officially but definitely won't be `otg` as it's just an internal codename for the project) so dbids would almost certainly get reshuffled if you translate the model again to leverage `otg`.

Use [external IDs](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/comparing-versions-viewer) to get consistent correlation between Viewer nodes/components and the original model design.

What issues with DBIDs did you run into exactly if the above doesn't help with what you are running into?